# How to add a button in Toaster in BluePrintJS react?

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

I can add a button in my toaster of BluePrintJS using React.createElement.

**Example:**

```
           Toaster
             .create()
             .show({ 
               message: React.createElement('button', {}, 'MyButton'), 
               intent: 'danger' 
            });
```

But I am getting an error when I am trying to use normal JSX. 
**Example:**

```
           Toaster
              .create()
              .show({ message: <Button>MyButton</Button>, intent: 'danger' 
            });
```

**Error details**- Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead. (no-angle-bracket-type-assertion)

I am getting this error on code editor. And getting parsing error on console.

How can I use JSX instead of React.createElement?

N.B. I am using React Hook

Comment: Could you update the error details!

Comment: Seems babel loader unable to identify `JSX` syntax. Could you verify/provide `webpack.config.js` file